# How to run a service on AWS ECS with container overrides?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sdk

On AWS ECS you can run a task, or a service.

If you run a task with [`run_task(**kwargs)`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.run_task), you have the option to override some task options, for example the container environment variables, this way you can configure the thing inside the container for example. That's great.

Now, I can't find a way how to do the same with [`create_service(**kwargs)`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.create_service). You can only specify a task, so the created container runs with configuration as specified in the task definition. No way to configure it.

Is there a way how to modify task in a service, or this is not possible with the AWS ECS service?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you think how services work, they create X number of replicas of the task. All instances of the task have the same parameters, because the purpose is scaling out the task - they should do the same job. Often the traffic is load-balanced (part of service configuration), so it is undesirable that a user will get different response next time than the previous request due to ending up on a task which is configured differently. So bottom line is - that's by design.

Because parameters are shared, if you need to change a parameter, you create a new definition of the task, and then launch that as a service (or update an existing service).

If you want the tasks to be aware of other tasks (and thus behave differently), for example to write data to different shards of a sharded store, you have to implement that in the task's logic.

Comment: I hope AWS will reconsider implementation because: 1) usually task ran manually during development phase and integrated to service later on, so it makes sense to keep definition similar 2) unique task definition for each ECS cluster makes them too tightly integrated and barely re-usable